# Experiments to go with introductory quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations

Is there a book or something describing experiments that I could read in conjunction with a theoretical book like Griffith?  It would helpful to know how the theory is verified experimentally.

I have searched and come up blank, appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Are you asking about experiments we can do now to demonstrate effects?  Or the experiments that were the initial observations?

Comment: Either or both would be great.